# library-preload.js VS library-preload.json in OpenUI5

Tags: gruntjs, sapui5

I have a OpenUI5 application that uses a custom library with data-sap-ui-preload="async" enabled. In the latest OpenUi5 Version 1.40.8, the runtime looks first for a library-preload.js file, before loading the library-preload.json file as a fallback.

2016-11-02 17:53:39.471540 failed to load 'XXX/library-preload.js' (undefined), falling back to library-preload.json -

But the openui5-grunt task openui5_preload 0.10.0 does not create a library-preload.js file, only a library-preload.json file.

How can i create a library-preload.js file?

Answer (score 1):

The changelog on https://github.com/SAP/grunt-openui5/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md indicates that this is new since v0.11.0

> Create library-preload.js files instead of .json

this works since ui5 v1.40